# Use Stack Overflow to answer likely questions in advance

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, self-promotion

I recently created an open source framework for Windows Phone 7 development, and started writing an FAQ on my GitHub wiki. I then realized that these questions are more likely to be asked on Stack Overflow (if anyone actually starts using the framework, that is...)

One thing that struck me was that I could ask these questions on Stack Overflow, and then answer them myself - with the added benefit of maybe making someone else interested in having a look at the framework. But, would that be douchy? I know that it is even encouraged to answer your own questions, but I'm afraid I will get bashed for trying to plug my own project..?

Comment: There is that danger ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you will get bashed for plugging your own project like that.  We've had people try this sort of thing before and it never ends well.

If you run into a problem while adding a feature or fixing a bug in your framework, feel free to ask a question and give a little bit of background on the project so we know what you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks, that was pretty much what I thought. I'll just have to keep bothering people on twitter instead.. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As Bill's answer indicated, self promotion is not desired.

One suggestion would be to point users to SO for questions outside your FAQ for the framework.  Then you and other users could help answer them.

Answer (score 2):

This is why people have blogs.